# How user event can be triggered in class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to use my own events in several classes.
I've seen similar questions. But i need a clear, correct example, like in ABC-book.

```
class Class2
{
    public bool Do_Some_thing()
    {
        bool there_is_no_errors=false;
        if (there_is_no_errors)
            trigger_User_event();
        return true;
    }
}
```

How this should be realized? Creating a new class or just in main code i can create obj-event and give it my class2?

```
public delegate void TriggerMyEvent(string message);
public event TriggerMyEvent MyEvent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events are declared and generated in a class and are associated with the event handler by using a delegate in the same class or in another class.

The class containing the event is used to publish the event. This is called the publisher class. Other classes that accept this event are called subscriber classes.

To declare an event inside a class, you must first declare the its delegate type. Then, declare the event using keyword `event`.

Here is a simple demo about how to subscribe to an event.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EventTest e = new EventTest(); /* Instantiate the object, without triggering event */
        subscribEvent v = new subscribEvent(); /* Instantiate object */
        e.ChangeNum += new EventTest.NumManipulationHandler(v.printf); /* subscribe the event */
        e.SetValue(7);
        e.SetValue(11);
    }
}

public class EventTest
{
    private int value;

    public delegate void NumManipulationHandler();

    public event NumManipulationHandler ChangeNum;
    protected virtual void OnNumChanged()
    {
        if (ChangeNum != null)
        {
            ChangeNum(); /* Trigger the event */
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("event not fire");
            Console.ReadKey(); /* Press enter to continue */
        }
    }

    public EventTest()
    {
        int n = 5;
        SetValue(n);
    }

    public void SetValue(int n)
    {
        if (value != n)
        {
            value = n;
            OnNumChanged();
        }
    }
}

// Subscriber class
public class subscribEvent
{
    public void printf()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("event fire");
        Console.ReadKey(); /* Press enter to continue */
    }
}
```